# Laravel 4 Queue - [InvalidArgumentException] There are no commands defined in the "queue" namespace

Tags: php, queue, laravel-4, supervisord, beanstalkd

I'm using Laravel 4 + Beanstalk + Supervisor on a CentOS 6 VPS.

It was already a pain to install both beanstalk and supervisor on the VPS, but I got through it (I have done this same installation on my local server, a Macbook Pro, and it's working fine there).

I want to take advantage of Laravel 4's Queues and Beanstalk to send email asynchronously. I have made a "program" for supervisor that basically runs the command

```
php artisan queue:listen --env=production
```

but the process associated to that won't start succesfully. The log I defined for this process outputs the following:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
There are no commands defined in the "queue" namespace.
```

So apparently artisan is finding something that it doesn't like at all.

Please, please, **PLEASE**, would you help me? Only results I've found on Google are an *unanswered* git issue post, and an equally useless thread with no answers on Laravel's forums.

**Edit**: Testing I've noticed that Artisan's queue:listen works fine when run by me in the shell, but when Supervisord tries to run the command, the InvalidArgumentException happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution in my case, if any one of you ever come across this issue, was the following:

I had supervisord version 2.1 installed (via pip). I needed at least version 3.0 (because the "directory" setting (used in the supervisord.conf file) was introduced in the version 3.0.

I had to

```
pip uninstall supervisor
```

Then I had to

```
pip install supervisor==3.0
```

After that, I just had to set the desired configuration values in /etc/supervisord.conf, and my `artisan` was running `queue:listen` without problems.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and got my answer to the question I posted that worked for me:

[Supervisord makes my Laravel queue:listen throw InvalidArgumentException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25018202/supervisord-makes-my-laravel-queuelisten-throw-invalidargumentexception)

Instead of doing:

```
[program:lvcartsey]
command=php artisan queue:listen --env="local"
stdout_logfile=/home/mike/web/app/storage/logs/myqueue_supervisord.log
redirect_stderr=true
directory=/home/mike/web
;autorestart=true
;autostart=true
user=mike
```

in the supervisor.conf i replaced the command with:

```
command=/usr/local/bin/php artisan queue:listen --env="local"
```