# Supervisord makes my Laravel queue:listen throw InvalidArgumentException

Tags: php, laravel, centos, supervisord

I'm having exactly the same issue as in the post here:

[Laravel 4 Queue - [InvalidArgumentException] There are no commands defined in the "queue" namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19062341/laravel-4-queue-invalidargumentexception-there-are-no-commands-defined-in-th).

Centos 6.5 Final.  Laravel 4.2, Supervisor 3.0 and Python 2.6.6

The config for the app:

```
[program:lvcartsey]
command=php artisan queue:listen --env="local"
stdout_logfile=/home/mike/web/app/storage/logs/myqueue_supervisord.log
redirect_stderr=true
directory=/home/mike/web
;autorestart=true
;autostart=true
user=mike
```

Once I start supervisor I get this in my myqueue_supervisord.log:

```
  [InvalidArgumentException]
  There are no commands defined in the "queue" namespace.
```

When run from the command line php artisan queue:listen works as expected.

I searched google, but I found no useful information regarding this issue.  Anyone knows what might be the cause of this?  How does running artisan from command line differ from supervisor running it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21704170/397195). It's probably a fix for you too.

What you want to do is to change

```
command=php artisan queue:listen --env="local"
```

to

```
command=/usr/local/bin/php artisan queue:listen --env="local"
```